# Using numpy.array throws an AttributeError

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror

I tried importing the numpy package in Python and faced a lot of problems initially because of the path variable. After handling that issue and importing numpy,using the array object gives me an attribute error.

```
>>import numpy
>>x=numpy.array([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>",line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

[My attempt of running that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2OGI.png)

Seems like your numpy was imported incorrectly. Did you try to use pip?

Comment: same here. I guess the problem is with your numpy installation.